# Is there a way to get the particular Values from JSON Array using robot or Python code?

Tags: python, robotframework

JSON OUTPUT:

```
${response}= [
{
  "Name":"7122Project",
  "checkBy":[
     {
        "keyId":"NA",
        "target":"1232"
     }
  ],
  "Enabled":false,
  "aceess":"123"
},
{
  "Name":"7122Project",
  "checkBy":[
     {
        "keyId":"_GU6S3",
        "target":"123"
     }
  ],
  "aceess":"11222",
  "Enabled":false
},
{
  "Name":"7122Project",
  "checkBy":[
     {
        "keyId":"-1lLUy",
        "target":"e123"
     }
  ],
  "aceess":"123"
}
]
```

Need to get the keyId values from json without using hardcoded index using robot?

I did

```
${ID}=    set variable    ${response[0]['checkBy'][0]['keyId']}
```

But I need to check the length get all keyID values and store the values that dose not contain NA
How can I do check length and use for loop using robot framework?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose you can have more elements in `checkBy` arrays, like so:

```py
response = [
    {
      "Name":"7122Project",
      "checkBy": [
         {
            "keyId": "NA",
            "target": "1232"
         }
      ],
      "Enabled": False,
      "aceess": "123"
    },
    {
      "Name": "7122Project",
      "checkBy": [
         {
            "keyId": "_GUO6g6S3",
            "target": "123"
         }
      ],
      "aceess": "11222",
      "Enabled": False
    },
    {
      "Name": "7122Project",
      "checkBy": [
         {
            "keyId": "-1lLlZOUy",
            "target": "e123"
         },
         {
            "keyId": "test",
            "target": "e123"
         }
      ],
      "aceess": "123"
    }
]
```

then you can key all `keyId`s in Python with this code:

```py
def get_key_ids(response):
    checkbys = [x["checkBy"] for x in response]
    key_ids = []

    for check_by in checkbys:
        for key_id in check_by:
            key_ids.append(key_id["keyId"])
    return key_ids
```

for the example above, it will return: `['NA', '_GUO6g6S3', '-1lLlZOUy', 'test_NA']`.

You want to get both ids with NA and without NA, so perhaps you can change the function a bit:

```py
def get_key_ids(response, predicate):
    checkbys = [x["checkBy"] for x in response]
    key_ids = []

    for check_by in checkbys:
        for key_id in check_by:
            if predicate(key_id["keyId"]):
                key_ids.append(key_id["keyId"])
    return key_ids
```

and use it like so:

```py
get_key_ids(response, lambda id: id == "NA")     # ['NA']
get_key_ids(response, lambda id: id != "NA")     # ['_GUO6g6S3', '-1lLlZOUy', 'test_NA']
get_key_ids(response, lambda id: "NA" in id)     # ['NA', 'test_NA']
get_key_ids(response, lambda id: "NA" not in id) # ['_GUO6g6S3', '-1lLlZOUy']
```

Now it's just a matter of creating a library and importing it into RF. You can get inspiration in the [official documentation](https://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/RobotFrameworkUserGuide.html#creating-test-libraries).

> But I need to check the length get all keyID values and store the values that dose not contain NA

I don't completely understand what you are up to. Do you mean length of keyId strings, like "NA" and its length of 2, or the number of keyIds in the response?

> How can I do check length and use for loop using robot framework?

You can use keyword [`Should Be Equal *`](https://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/libraries/BuiltIn.html#Should%20Be%20Equal) from BuiltIn library. Some examples of for loops could be found in the user guide [here](https://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/RobotFrameworkUserGuide.html#templates-with-for-loops).

Now you should have all the parts you need to accomplish your task, you can try to put it all together.